# How to use mountpoint to verify multiple directories using variables shell/py

Tags: scripting, mount, python

if trying to automated this checks, how would py function work with shell

```bash
def success():
    print("###    ####end")
    print("###end")

# It can be called when the script fails and output the failed signal.
def failure():
    print("### ####end")
    print("###end")

# It can be called when the script needs to Export results.Separate multiple export results with \n.
# if you want to output multi line messages, you can call the function multiple times or add newline characters, for example, output("aaaaa\nbbbbb\nccccc\nddddd")
# Note: 1. If you create a job by calling an interface, the script can obtain the script output from the output field only by calling the output function.
# Note: 2. Only output messages are exported by the Export Result button on the page.
def output(msg):
    print("### ####end")
    print(msg)
    print("###end")

# Special output function for inspection work, output inspection results.Multiple inspection results are separated by %.
# example: inspect_output("$item_name1%$item_name2%$item_name3")
# Note: The inspection task definition script must use the inspect_output function.
def inspect_output(msg):
    print("### ####end")
    print("inspect_output:{msg} end".format(msg=msg))
    print("###end")
 
# Note:script content in the main function. Ensure that you call function success or failure.Otherwise, the system cannot capture the script output information.
def main():
    # Note: if output logs are needed, direct print(xxx) can be used.
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what is wrong with ```mount -t $filesystem```, e.g. mount -t xfs ?

Comment: ideally to focus on mount directory if its valid or not, in a case of directory exists , mount failed.  let's say we have couple of types of fs , with different mount directories, im considering writing into existing mounting directories to valid or check if directories - subs are not empty

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a directory is "simply" a directory, or if it is used as a mountpoint, there is the `mountpoint` tool from the `util-linux` package.

Usage example

- simple directory

  ```
  ~$ mkdir testdir
  ~$ mountpoint testdir
  testdir is not a mountpoint
  ```
- mount a filesystem to the directory

  ```
  ~$ sudo mount /my/external/filesystem testdir
  ~$ mountpoint testdir
  testdir is a mountpoint
  ```

If you want to use it in shell scripts for automated tests, there is also a silent mode available:

```bash
if mountpoint -q testdir
then
    # perform operations on the mounted filesystem
else
    echo "Error, nothing mounted on testdir!"
fi
```

Comment: the directory could be always there once mount suceed , but doesn't mean everytime node reboot mount are sucess . key area if we could check whether direcotry works, or mount status active/enabled?

Comment: @user538051 I'm not sure if I understand you. If you reboot the node and the mount fails, that means that no filesystem is mounted to `testdir`, and `mountpoint` would return `testdir is not a mountpoint`...

Comment: but there's also case mount failed but there's directory exists / created manually from previous. let's say we have multiple mountpoint , some are sucess, some are not.

Comment: @user538051 Yes, but as you can see in my example, if I create the directory manually but don't mount anything to it, it will be correctly identified as "just a directory". So if the directory that is intended to be used as a mountpoint exists, but nothing is mounted to it (not yet, or because an attempt to mount failed), it should be treated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to make sure that all mounts were properly mounted before writing data to those directories. If that is correct I would suggest to set a immutable flag on the directory before mounting it. Here is an example:

```
[user@host ~]$ mkdir ./1 && sudo chattr +i ./1
[user@host ~]$ sudo touch 1/test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘1/test.txt’: Permission denied
[user@host ~]$ sudo mount -t tmpfs none 1
[user@host ~]$ touch 1/test.txt && ls -l 1/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Aug 18 10:49 1/test.txt
```

Comment: suppose if you have multiple mountpoints to check,   how would you mountpoint -q [check multiple directories] if not mount them again